# Win32 DLL ImportError when importing jpy module into python

Tags: python-2.7, 64-bit, python-import

I'm trying to begin to use the [snappy module](https://senbox.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SNAP/Configure+Python+to+use+the+SNAP-Python+%28snappy%29+interface) on my system. This is the satellite image processing module developed by the European Space Agency -- there are at least two other python modules available with identical or similar names which are not included in my libraries. I set it up following the instructions given in the link. However, the import fails:

```
import snappy
```

gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-44a854c9871f>", line 1, in <module>
    import snappy

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\snappy\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    import jpy

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

As expected, 'import jpy' gives the same error.
I suspect this is related to some part of my system relying on 32-bit addressing while everything else relies on 64-bit. However, to me it looks like everything is 64-bit.

I've tried all the accepted answers StackOverflow questions featuring that error to no avail.

### My system:

My shell (Spyder, IPython or JupyterQT) prints the following at start-up:

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 19 2016, 13:29:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

I'm running:

- Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit
- SNAP Desktop 4.0.0, 64-bit (the satellite image processing application that the snappy module relies on)
- Programming environment: Anaconda2 4.3.0, 64-bit with Python 2.7.13
- I had removed a 32-bit distribution of Python 2.7 that came with ArcMap. I couldn't find a trace of it on my system anymore which is good (if true).
  I'm not sure how to check for sure if the snappy module I have is written for 32-bit or 64-bit architectures but [the development website](https://senbox.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SNAP/How+to+use+the+SNAP+API+from+Python) states:

> Please note that you must use a 32-bit Python if your SNAP installation is 32-bit and accordingly use a 64-bit Python if your SNAP installation is 64-bit.

### This will be hard to reproduce:

I followed roughly the same steps (removed a 32-bit Python distribution of Python 2.7 [PythonX,Y] and replaced it by Anaconda2 4.3.0, installed snappy from the link given above, etc.) on my other machine yesterday and `import snappy` worked flawlessly. That machine is running SNAP Desktop 5.0 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Re-installing of a newer version of SNAP Desktop solved the problem.**

In detail:

- I uninstalled SNAP 4.0.0 via the usual route through 'programs and features' in 'control panel'.
- I removed the 'snappy' folder from `<python directory>/Lib/site-packages`.
- I downloaded the SNAP 5.0.0 installer.
- I ran the installer and selected the option to set up SNAP for Python.
- I installed the `snappy` module by typing the following code into `cmd.exe`, as I had done before and as described in the first link in the question.

  cd c:/users/--myusername--/.snap/snap-python/snappy
  c:/anaconda2/python.exe setup.py install
  Replace `--myusername--` with your windows username and keep in mind that your python installation is probably not located at `c:/anaconda2`.

And voila, `import snappy` works. If you face this particular problem too, you should probably also check if `help(snappy)` gives the expected result, to make sure you don't have a different package also called `snappy` installed.